# Want to parse podcast feed in php

Tags: php, rss, feed, simplepie, podcast

I want to get the audio and logo URLs for each episode of the podcast using php.

First I try to use simplepie to parse feed. But, it so complex for me. I only found how to get podcast episode's logo. but I can't find the way to get URL of the audio file from RSS.

Next I try to use the package link below. But when I try to use it, I get an error like that " Error  Call to undefined function Lukaswhite\PodcastFeedParser\Parser().".
https://github.com/lukaswhite/podcast-feed-parser

PS. If you are try for this. This repository's redme file is incorrect.

```
composer require lukaswhite/php-feed-parser
```

use this.

```
composer require lukaswhite/podcast-feed-parser
```

Comment: _"PS. If you are try for this. This repository's redme file is incorrect."_ - That should be added as an issue on that github-repo, not here on stackoverflow.

Comment: There's a [pull request](https://github.com/lukaswhite/podcast-feed-parser/pull/2) for this already

Comment: Podcast feeds are just XML. Why not just use PHPs own [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)? And if you get stuck on something _specific_ along the way, you need to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also make sure to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Currently, there's no proper question here for us to answer, since we have _no idea_ how you've implemented anything.

Comment: It first time to writing on this site. And my English is poor.

Comment: I’ll try simpleXML.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.